# java.sql.SqlRecoverableException while querying oracle cube

Tags: java, oracle11g, olap

I get the following error when I try to query a cube (based on Oracle Olap 11gr2) from a Java program
java.sql.SqlRecoverableException: no more data to read from the socket.

This error occurs sometimes and sometimes it does not occur.

We observed that if many people simultaneously try to query the cube the error crops up.

Is this a bug or is there a solution or a method to deal with this sort of situation

Answer (score 1):

You are either experiencing a bug or you are reaching your servers resource limits.

Technically the reason is Oracle ending your connection without "telling" you. Whenever your client want to go on using the connection, this fails with above message.

Normally Oracle will write a crash dump before closing down your connection. Ask your DBA if you have a matching entry in the alert log of your Server. You can query the alert log configuration with `SELECT * FROM  V$DIAG_INFO;`
and query the alert log itself by using `V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT`

See [Oracle Documentation for alert logs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/diag005.htm) and [Don Burleson's Blog on Alert Logs](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_v$diag_alert_ext.htm)